# Find value and its index in a series just like which() in R

Tags: python, r, find, match

I'm dealing with a date series and I wanted to find out the element that matches with date 2009/12/1.

In R, I can simply write

```
idx = which(d_series,as.Date("2009/10/1","%Y/%m/%d"))
```

However in Python I cannot find any functions that can be used like this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you mean the `list.index` method? as in `['a','b','c'].index('b') -> 1`?

Comment: @isedev Did you mean 2?

Comment: no, 1 is correct. The index is zero based... ['a','b','c'][1] -> 'b'

Comment: I think so, but Im dealing with pandas series. The list.index doesn't work. I finally used series.isin() then series.ix() combined but Im not sure if it's the most efficient way.